# How can i use var() in css in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-design-system, style

This is what I'am trying to do:

HTML:

```
<li class="navBar2" style="--lwc-beforeColor: #0ec2df"></li>
```

.css

```
.navBar2{
    height:29px;
    background-color: var(--lwc-beforeColor); 
}
```

But this doesn't work. I wonder if this is not correct way to use var() in css in LWC. Please help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can define custom properties either in components to make them local or load them from StaticResource, if they are not already present on the page.

Salesforce by default loads its' properties in `:root`, but you can't use `:root` in LWC components.

So if you want to make property component-specific use something like this.

```
/* CSS */
:host {
   --bgColor: green;
}
.title {
    background-color: var(--bgColor);
}
```

If you want to make them global you need to load them from StaticResource

```
/* Resource.css */
:root {
   --titleFontSize: 16px;
}
```

```
// component.js
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import styles from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Resource';
// ...
connectedCallback() {
  loadStyle(this, styles + 'pathtoStyle.css');
}
// ...
```

```
/* component.css */
.title {
    font-size: var(--titleFontSize);
}
```

**UPDATE**
you can also get/set properties dynamically.

you can get values from apex and/or set them with JS

```
// controller.js

isFirstRender = true;
renderedCallback() {
  if (!this.isFirstRender) {
     return;
  }
  this.isFirstRender = false;

  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--titleColor', 'red');
  const customProperty = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue('--titleColor');

}
```

```
/* component.css */
:host {
  display: block;
  color: var(--titleColor);
}
```

Comment: In the .css class below:
.title {
    font-size: var(--titleFontSize);
}

Is there any way we can get value of "--titleFontSize" dynamically from backend(js, apex) not from static resource?

Comment: theoretically, you can set/get variables with JS, https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/ but I never tried it

Comment: wow, it works. I will update my answer

Comment: @Akshay_Matura_SFDC updated my answer

Comment: Is it enough for you or need something additional?

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok, please mark then my answer as accepted

Comment: @ytiq You can now use [Style Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) without necessarily injecting global styles.

Comment: Thanks, just read it, but to be honest I didn't get the difference. So you can use `:root` in components now? I remember Salesforce announced that you override some standard SFDC variables, but I don't think it's related to it

Answer (score 2):

Not my code, forget where I got it from...

**Controller:**

```
    titleColor;
    isFirstRender;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (!this.isFirstRender) {
            return;
        }
        this.isFirstRender = false;
        var bodyStyles = document.body.style;
        bodyStyles.setProperty('--titleColor', this.titleColor);
    }
```

**CSS:**

```
.control-titleColor {
    background-color: var(--titleColor);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<...class={control-titleColor}..>
```

Comment: You can check out [Style Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) for more details.