# jQuery hide button before even shown

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have installed a managed package that has a static resource (JS). This static resource performs a jQuery "prepend" to show a button. I cannot change the code of this static resource but i have the ability to create another static resource (JS) and write some code for customizations. The thing is: a Visualforce page is loaded (i have no access to the VF Page code) and then my custom static resource is loaded and then the managed package static resource is loaded. Their static resource, performs a prepend on a button, but i want this button to always be hidden. But, although i add the command to hide the button, it is not. I suppose it's because the button is loaded after my command... Has anyone face this problem again? Is there a way to solve it?

Code below:
Managed package static resource code that performs the "prepend"

```
jQuery(buttons[0]).prepend('<button id="addonman" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral">Add On Manager</button>');
jQuery('#addonman').click(showFullManager)
```

My static resource

```
CS.EventHandler.subscribe(CS.EventHandler.Event.AFTER_SHOW_SCREEN_ACTION, function (payload) {
//? Test functionality...
      jQuery("#addonman").hide();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using custom css with `visibility: hidden` in the static resource? If you can apply the css instead of using jquery, you can avoid the timing issue. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/341324/how-to-let-the-end-users-override-css-of-managed-packages-lwc
https://www.infallibletechie.com/2020/09/how-to-use-css-in-static-resource-in.html

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use separate .css file, it needs to be in Javascript cause it must have logic whether it should be hidden or not. In any case, thank you @SophiaGigliotti :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it *needs* to be JavaScript, just add a CSS rule:

```
CS.EventHandler.subscribe(CS.EventHandler.Event.AFTER_SHOW_SCREEN_ACTION, 
function (payload) {
//? Test functionality...
      document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("#addonman { display: none; }");
});
```

By adding it as a rule, you can technically do it whenever you want, even *before* the button is rendered into the page.

If you can choose to import CSS, you can just make it a rule:

```
#addonman {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @sfdcfox !