# How to set consistent styling across many LWCs using styling hooks?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds, slds-styling-hooks

This [Style Components Using Lightning Design System Styling Hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_css_custom_properties) documentation illustrates how to set custom properties on an individual custom LWC to change the styling:

```
/* myBaseButton.css */
:host {
  --slds-c-button-brand-color-background: orange;
  --slds-c-button-brand-color-border: orange;
  /* Other CSS custom properties here */
}
```

and it looks like a lot more properties are now available.

Is there presently any way to define a set of a couple of dozen of these **once** and have them used in many custom components? Or is that what [theming will allow](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/#Styling-Hooks-FAQ-Theming):

> **What About Theming Custom Properties?**
>
> For Winter ‘21, component-level
> customizations (e.g. --slds-c-*) will be the only custom properties
> that will be available.
>
> Global styling capabilities that allow theming are in the works but
> not within the scope of Winter ‘21. When global styling is introduced,
> it will be an additive feature that will not break any of your
> existing styling hooks usage.

**PS**

Perhaps could be done via code similar to this [How to let the end users override CSS of managed package's LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/341324/how-to-let-the-end-users-override-css-of-managed-packages-lwc) though I don't need the runtime switching.

**PPS**

Is this the best approach at the moment [loading from a static resource using loadStyle](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294284/how-can-i-use-var-in-css-in-lwc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid `loadStyle` "workaround" as it's essentially going around the design of LWC and there's no guarantee that behavior won't change or be blocked in a future update.

Instead, you can create a single css file that leverages these styling hooks and share it across all your LWCs.

[Share CSS Style Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_share)

- cssLibrary

  - cssLibrary.css
  - cssLibrary.js-meta.xml

```css
/* define the styling hooks as you'd like */
:host {
    --slds-c-badge-color-background: #0c9dda;
    --slds-c-badge-text-color: #c21010;
    --slds-c-button-brand-color-background: orange;
    --slds-c-button-brand-color-border: orange;
  }
```

Then, in your custom LWC - you import the css

```css
@import 'c/cssLibrary';
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-badge">Traveler</div>
    <div class="slds-badge">Welcoming</div>
    <lightning-button label="click me" variant="brand"></lightning-button>
</template>
```

[image]

---

You didn't mention community, bu figured I'd point out the [--dxp styling hooks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4bvx.png) for Lightning Web Runtime (LWR) Sites, where you can set a single hook that affects both base & custom Lightning Web Components throughout.

```css
<style>
  /**
   * Scoped to the root of the document and all its descendant elements.
   */
  :root {
    --sds-c-button-color-background: peachpuff;
  }
 
  /**
   * Scoped to any element with the class applied and all its descendant elements
   */
  .container {
    --sds-c-button-color-background: peachpuff;
  }
</style>
```

Though it does mention

> We recommend using --dxp styling hooks to make general changes across the components in you site. But if the --dxp branding defaults don’t provide exactly what you need, you can use --sds styling hooks to fine-tune the appearance of individual components where necessary.

Comment: Thanks Kris, I take your point of needing to stay away from things that work today but may not tomorrow. Will go with what you have shown. And also look at the `--dxp` stuff.